# Parameterize a Login Screen?

Tags: android, authentication, parameters

How can I parameter a screen in Android?

I need to show a different image on the login screen, depending who opens the app. In other words, I want to have to build only one app, but have three different login screens, and I want to choose one of them and publish separately. If I wanted so, I could install the three variations on one device.

**Every login screen is going to have a different `ImageView`**

Is there a way to do this without having to have three different projects?

Comment: What is wrong with a simple if-statement within the login screen code?

Comment: That is not a bad idea. I actually thought of that too, but I prefered to use flavors, because I will need to have different instances inside my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create [flavors](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html) for each product version (each one with a different applicationId)

EX:

project.gradle

```
productFlavors {
        test3 {
              applicationId "com.test.3"

        }
        test2 {
             applicationId "com.test.2"

        }
        test1 {
            applicationId "com.test.1"

        }
    }
```

then you can use `BuildConfig.FLAVOR` inside your java classes:

EX:

```
    if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("test3")) {
        setContentView(R.layout.login3);
    } else if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("test2")) {
        setContentView(R.layout.login2);
    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.login1);
    }
```

Comment: I think I can understand what you mean, but could you elaborate it a little? :D

Comment: @DavidCoelho check now